# Keeping content inside modal box

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

I'm attempting to create a month calendar pop-up inside my app using a material UI Modal where you can select the day. I'm running into an issue where the modal does not fit the size of my calendar. how can I fix this? (Open calendar modal by clicking the date in top right between the two arrows) thank you! all code below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-pine-owsxg1?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Make the sandbox forkable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modal doesn't fit the size of calendar because you set the width of calendar container to 400. Delete the row with `width: 400,` from your style object in `dayview.js` file and modal will take as much space as it needs to fit the content of your calendar

Comment: so funny because i just realized this like 10 sec ago lmao silly me, appreciate the help.